# I cannot install and run the basic Svelte demo on my company computer

Tags: npm, proxy, svelte

I am trying to install the basic Svelte demo project on my company laptop and it fails. This is most likely related to the increased security and proxy we are using. On my private PC, everything worked like a charm in seconds, but on the company laptop I've been struggling for days running around in circles.

The steps I am taking are:

```
npm create svelte@latest myapp --proxy http://<username>:"<pasword>"@<proxyserver>:<port>
cd myapp
npm install --proxy http://<username>:"<pasword>"@<proxyserver>:<port>
```

Already at this stage I get multiple warnings and errors starting with:

`npm WARN cleanup Failed to remove some directories [`

but with many more cleanup warnings, and then multiple errors, starting with:

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path c:\Users\manioko\source\repos\myapp\node_modules\esbuild
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node install.js
npm ERR! node:internal/errors:867
```

I have tried several things, including setting:

```
npm config set -ssl false
npm config set registry "http://registry.npmjs.org/"
```

But none of these fixes seem to work for me. Any ideas on what could be wrong here? I really cannot even get started with this one...

I would happily attach the log file, if there was a way to do it. Let me know if you want me to just post it as code in a comment or something.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, it proved to be a company security restriction that blocked files from running.

I resolved it by getting a separate Virtual Machine for the development of this tool.